# Python script with many elif for GPIO in and out

Tags: python, gpio

I wrote a python script to detect momentary button presses and record each to a file. Upon each press, an LED will also light up through GPIO.OUT. 
The original file works wonders, however I'm currently needing to add two more buttons into the mix (4 total now) and each will also write to a file plus have an LED light up. When I execute the script I thought should work, only button 1 works. Any help for how to debug the non-working code is appreciated.

NON-WORKING CODE (4 BUTTON):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial
import syslog
import MySQLdb as mdb
import subprocess

poursdir = '/var/www/RPints'
path = '/var/www/RPints/includes/pours.php'

outpin1 = 26
inpin1 = 18
outpin2 = 16
inpin2 = 23
outpin3 = 6
inpin3 = 17
outpin4 = 5
inpin4 = 22

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(outpin1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outpin2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin2, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outpin3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin3, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outpin4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin4, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    value1 = GPIO.input(inpin1) 
    value2 = GPIO.input(inpin2)
    value3 = GPIO.input(inpin3)
    value4 = GPIO.input(inpin4)
    if not value1 or value2 or value3 or value4:     
        GPIO.output(outpin1, 0)
        GPIO.output(outpin2, 0)
        GPIO.output(outpin3, 0)
        GPIO.output(outpin4, 0)
    else:
        if value1:
            GPIO.output(outpin1, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "1", "1"])
        elif value2:
            GPIO.output(outpin2, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "2", "1"])
        elif value3:
            GPIO.output(outpin3, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "3", "1"])
        elif value4:
            GPIO.output(outpin4, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "4", "1"])
    time.sleep(.3)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

---

WORKING CODE (2 BUTTON):

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial
import syslog
import MySQLdb as mdb
import subprocess

poursdir = '/var/www/RPints'
path = '/var/www/RPints/includes/pours.php'

outpin1 = 26
inpin1 = 18
outpin2 = 16
inpin2 = 23

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(outpin1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outpin2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin2, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    value1 = GPIO.input(inpin1) 
    value2 = GPIO.input(inpin2)
    if not value1 and not value2:    
        GPIO.output(outpin1, 0)
        GPIO.output(outpin2, 0)
    else:
        if value1 and not value2:
            GPIO.output(outpin1, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "1", "1"])
        elif value2 and not value1:
            GPIO.output(outpin2, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "2", "1"])
    time.sleep(.3)
    time.sleep(.05) 
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Why did you change the 'if not value1 or value2 or value3 or value4' logic? It's different in the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldnt you be checking for the full
set of values? ie

```
if not value1 and not value2 and not value3 and not value4:
       # reset
elif value1 and not value2 and not value3 and not value4:
      #light up led 1
elif not value1 and value2 and not value3 and not value4:
      #light up led 2
elif not value1 and not value2 and value3 and value4:
     #light up 3
elif not value1 and not value2 and not value3 and value4
      #light up 4
```

Comment: I didn't check for the full set because i will only ever press one button at a time. I did try to add the "and not valueX" for each but it didn't help my outcome so I left it out for simplicity. In the end, maybe it's a good idea to include just in case.

Comment: I'm back in business, basically following your logic. However, it hangs up after the 4th elif statement. I have put in a print statment for each elif, nothing prints until the 4th and it loops continuously.What might I need to add to get this to stop? Adding an else afterwards didnt do anything because it couldn't get to the else. 

After typing this, maybe its a wire short. Just in case, tell me if you think code can be added to fix.

Comment: As I expected, no extra code was required after switching all to and not except when each condition is left as True for elif statements. The problem was the GPIO pin I chose, 22, which is defaulting to out so the script thought the button was always pressed after each .3 second rest. Thanks for the thoughts all!

Answer (score 0):

Ahah! It took me a minute, but I realized that when you say `if not value1 or value2 or value3 or value4:` The way python reads it, if value1 is false (which it is if you press any other button), if seems like this:

```
if True or False or False or False:
    print "write zero"
```

Python reads `if not value1` and the various ors (which don't matter). Because value1 is false (when you press any button but it), and `not value1` is True, it does what is in the `if` block. You thought that it would read "if not any of these, do this", but what it actually is doing is reading "if the opposite of this or any of these". To fix it go back to using `and not value2` etc for your 4-button script.

Edit: yep @compie is right, the logic is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a switch-style statement instead. For instance:

```
def press(event):
    return {
        'value1': 1,
        'value2': 2,
        'value3': 3,
        'value4': 4,
}.get(event,None)

while True:
    v1 = GPIO.input(inp1) 
    v2 = GPIO.input(inp2)
    v3 = GPIO.input(inp3)
    v4 = GPIO.input(inp4)

    values = [v1,v2,v3,v4]

    for event in values: 
        press(event)

        #for debugging only..
        if not event == 'None':
            print(press(event))
```

That creates a function that will take in any value, and figure out which value it is, and return a code to you depending on what it received.

The while loop obviously just constantly checks for a non 'None' value in each GPIO input.

I haven't had a chance to test this on a Pi, so there could be something I'm missing, but I think this could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial
import syslog
import MySQLdb as mdb
import subprocess

poursdir = '/var/www/RPints'
path = '/var/www/RPints/includes/pours.php'

outpin1 = 26
inpin1 = 18
outpin2 = 16
inpin2 = 23
outpin3 = 6
inpin3 = 17
outpin4 = 5
inpin4 = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(outpin1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outpin2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin2, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outpin3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin3, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outpin4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(inpin4, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    value1 = GPIO.input(inpin1) 
    value2 = GPIO.input(inpin2)
    value3 = GPIO.input(inpin3)
    value4 = GPIO.input(inpin4)
    if not value1 and not value2 and not value3 and not value4:  
        GPIO.output(outpin1, 0)
        GPIO.output(outpin2, 0)
        GPIO.output(outpin3, 0)
        GPIO.output(outpin4, 0)
    else:
        if value1 and not value2 and not value3 and not value4:
            GPIO.output(outpin1, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "1", "1"])
        elif not value1 and value2 and not value3 and not value4:
            GPIO.output(outpin2, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "2", "1"])
        elif not value1 and not value2 and value3 and not value4:
            GPIO.output(outpin3, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "3", "1"])
        elif not value1  and not value2 and not value3 and value4:
            GPIO.output(outpin4, 1)
            subprocess.call(["php", path, "4", "1"])

    time.sleep(.3)
    time.sleep(.05)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

As the comments say, I added back in the "and not" for each condition except when I want to evaluate if each button is "True". Also, pin setup was changed from out as 22 to 4 for the 4th button to solve the continuous on situation.